# Constant 401 Unauthorized while trying to access an API

Tags: postman, apiconnect

I am pretty sure my ID and secret are correct.
Here's the link to the yours truly: (https://sandbox.mngkargo.com.tr/en/node/266)

> POST https://testapi.mngkargo.com.tr/mngapi/api/token
> Headers:
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> X-IBM-Client-Id: [ID goes here]
> X-IBM-Client-Secret: [Secret goes here]
> x-api-version: v1

The response I constantly get:

```
Code: 401 Unauthorized
Headers:
content-type: application/json
{
  "httpCode": "401",
  "httpMessage": "Unauthorized",
  "moreInformation": "Invalid client id or secret."
}
```

Please don't bother throwing rocks at me for my incompetency. For I am already a very broken man.

Couldn't work it through Postman either. At this point I'm starting to change professions while I am still young.

Comment: I tested it on `https://sandbox.mngkargo.com.tr/` , In Identity API 1.0, JWT Token is required to use our APIs. I got the same error 401(Invalid client id or secret.). It seems defect itself.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote api secret wrong
You will first create a subscription to identity, then select API user.
There are two different verifications in the identity method, the first is api key and api secret verification with auth, and the other is the customer id and password section in the body section.